# How to re register an app on Windows 10 RS5?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have `AppxBundle`file of Forza Horizon 4, downloaded it manually. Installed it using:

```
add-appxpackage Microsoft.SunriseGame.EAppxBundle
```

and it was successful, renamed the file to have a shorter name. the problem is Windows store does not detect it, the name of the app is not listed in the Windows store Installed apps, I can't seem to update it when an update becomes available for it.

I've done the same procedure for another app, a 35GB game Sea of Thieves, and it worked just fine, the app appeared in the list of Installed apps on Windows store.
any idea how to manually register that app so that Windows store can detect it and list it as installed app?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you have to use the `-DisableDevelopmentMode` switch with `Add-AppxPackage`. Have a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx)

Comment: @Theo can you please tell me the full command? I add that switch but then powershell asks me register: and Idk what to write so I get an error. also it seems like it wants me to give it an XML file but I only have EAppxBundle which I downloaded straight from Microsoft servers.

Comment: Register is used for XML manifests, such as: Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.23816.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppXManifest.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Some of the troubleshooting steps listed here may help:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/error-0x803f8001-window-10/45d2902c-5f4d-437c-98bb-34a45aacdd3c

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest}"
```

or

**Go to Settings --> Apps --> apps & features --> (game that's didn't work) --> advanced options --> reset**

or

Open Services.msc -> Windows PushToInstall Service -> Start Service

a user on reddit also tried to this for Forza Horizons 4 Demo, but had a corrupted package,

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9j673w/trying_to_use_the_addappxpackage_feature/